# Salesforce formula contains multiple check

Tags: formula

EDIT:

```
IF(
    OR(
        CONTAINS('ABC:'CBC', EmployeeActive__c),
        ISBLANK(EmployeeActive__c)
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

END:

the below formula works fine when I test with the contains `abc` or `cbc` but the issue I'm facing is if the `EmployeeActive__c` is empty value then it's defaulted to `Yes` in my case it should be `No` because its has empty. If I test with something like `aaa` or `bbb` then it's return `No` which is good. But the only issue I'm having is if the there is no value.

Any reason why it's treating empty value?

> IF(CONTAINS("ABC:CBC", EmployeeActive__c), "Yes","No")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below formula.

```
    IF(
    OR(
        CONTAINS(EmployeeActive__c,'ABC'),
        CONTAINS(EmployeeActive__c,'CBC'),
        CONTAINS(EmployeeActive__c,'abc'),
        CONTAINS(EmployeeActive__c,'cbc')
        
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

Comment: yea instead of repeating the case I would use `LOWER(EmployeeActive__c )`

Answer (score 0):

When using this function in a formula fields that are blank are considered valid.

Working what I have asked for:

```
IF(
    OR(
        CONTAINS(LOWER(EmployeeActive__c),'abc'),
        CONTAINS(LOWER(EmployeeActive__c),'cbc') 
        
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```